# Redirect User based on Timezone

Tags: javascript, redirect, timezone

I was wondering if there was a way using JavaScript to redirect a user based on their timezone?

Like if timezone is between gmt-12 and gmt-8 redirect to page1.htm for example.

I was looking at getTimezoneOffset() but I don't know how to make it redirect based on the result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location):

```
var date = new Date(),
    offset = date.getTimezoneOffset();

if (offset <= 720 && offset >= 960) {
  window.location.href = 'page1.htm';
}
```

Comment: That should be `<=` and `>=` repectively. It's impossible to meet the criteria above.

Comment: @rjz—I think you were better to leave it as minutes, there are 30 and 15 minute offsets in some places so conversion to hours introduces floats where integers would do.